# Sticky Navigation and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Having a bit of a problem. Looking to build a sticky nav, and when the sticky nav triggers, adding the 'is-sticky' class, i'd like to add a different class to another div.

Below is the code..

Thanks

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $(".sticky-wrapper").hasClass("is-sticky") ) {
      $("#menu-item-25").css({display: "inline"});
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you describe, what is not-working with your code?

Comment: We're going to need more detail as this doesn't really explain what you're asking for, have you got some code we can look at/test out?

Answer (score 0):

To add a class you need

```
$("#element").addClass('myclass');
```

You can also remove a class with

```
$("#element").removeClass('myclass');
```

And toggle a class with

```
$("#element").toggleClass('myclass');
```

But your code is far away from a sticky nav, here is how I do it

```
$(function() {

// grab the initial top offset of the navigation
var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('nav').offset().top;

// our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
var sticky_navigation = function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

    // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
    // otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
        $('nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px', 'left': '0px', 'line-height': '30px' });

    } else {
        $('nav').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top': '0px' });

    }  
};

// run our function on load
sticky_navigation();

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
});


});
```

Obviously you'll have to play around with the css

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here that I'm not sure about, but:

You need an event listener that leads to code that adds/removes the classes/css that you want. What you have now is an event listener, but it's listening for the document ready state, not a scroll that triggers a sticky nav. So:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //add a listener for something that would indicate a sticky-state change, presumably scrolling
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
      checkForStickyNav();
  });

  function checkForStickyNav() {
    //look for sticky nav, and prevent running over and over
    if ( $(".sticky-wrapper").hasClass("is-sticky") && !$(".otherStuff").hasClass("stickyfied") {
      //do your stuff here; presumably changing CSS as appropriate
      //make sure to add something along the lines of 'stickyfied' above, so that you don't keep re-adding the css on every scroll event
      $("#menu-item-25").css({display: "inline"});
      $('.otherStuff').addClass('stickyfied');
    } 
</script>
```